# "Hot food had to be served piping hot" means?

Tags: meaning

Does it refer to the food temperature or degree of spiciness?

Comment: We would just say "Food had to be served piping hot". The initial 'hot' is redundant, unnecessary, and clumsy.

Comment: "Hot food" presumably contrasts with rules for cold food. You wouldn't advise ice cream to be served piping hot, but possibly below a certain temperature.

Answer (score 6):

*Piping hot* means extremely hot, and refers to temperature.

The sentence is not redundant; it means that hot (temperature) food had to be served very hot, not just somewhat hot.